# Classic ASP Cookie Authentication Code Not Working

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I've received the cookie authentication code below from one of my vendors.

Supposedly is this classic ASP code but when I plug it into my classic asp program, it crashes with a 500 server error.

Is the code below truly classic asp?  Can anyone tell me why this code does not work in classic asp?

Thank you!

Sal

=========================

```vb
Function DeCrypt(ByVal strEncrypted As String, ByVal strKey As String) As String 
    ' cookie data is stored urlencoded and must be decoded before processing
    strEncrypted = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(strEncrypted)

    Dim iKeyChar As String
    Dim iStringChar As String
    Dim iDeCryptChar As String
    Dim strDecrypted As String = String.Empty

    For i As Integer = 0 To strEncrypted.Length - 1
        iKeyChar = Asc(strKey(i)).ToString()
        iStringChar = Asc(strEncrypted(i)).ToString()
        iDeCryptChar = iKeyChar Xor iStringChar
        strDecrypted &= Chr(iDeCryptChar)
    Next

    Return strDecrypted
End Function
```

Comment: That's VB.Net code

Comment: Also, if you're counting on this for anything important, you should know it's not real encryption. It barely even qualifies as a cipher.

Comment: Oh... and in the vendor's defense, some people are starting to refer to older pre-MVC ASP.Net WebForms code as "classic". Personally I think it's a mistake, but I've seen it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

no, it looks like vb.net code. it's easy enough to convert over:

```vb
Function DeCrypt(strEncrypted, strKey) ' cookie data is stored urlencoded and must be decoded before processing 

strEncrypted = URLDecode(strEncrypted)
Dim iKeyChar
Dim iStringChar
Dim iDeCryptChar
Dim strDecrypted
Dim i

For i = 0 To strEncrypted.Length - 1
    iKeyChar = CStr(Asc(strKey(i)))
    iStringChar = CStr(Asc(strEncrypted(i)))
    iDeCryptChar = iKeyChar Xor iStringChar
    strDecrypted = strDecrypted & Chr(iDeCryptChar)
Next

URLDecode = strDecrypted
End Function

FUNCTION URLDecode(str)
'// This function:
'// - decodes any utf-8 encoded characters into unicode characters eg. (%C3%A5 = å)
'// - replaces any plus sign separators with a space character
'//
'// IMPORTANT:
'// Your webpage must use the UTF-8 character set. Easiest method is to use this META tag:
'// <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
'//
    Dim objScript
    Set objScript = Server.CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    objScript.Language = "JavaScript"
    URLDecode = objScript.Eval("decodeURIComponent(""" & str & """.replace(/\+/g,"" ""))")
    Set objScript = NOTHING
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  My programs currently use the following:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">  Will converting to charset=utf-8 affect anything else?

Comment: Good morning.  I just tried using the cookie authentication code supplied above however, my asp program crashed with a "500 Internal Server Error" which leads me to believe there's a syntax error in the code supplied.  Also, is it possible to run the cookie authentication and use charset=iso-8859-1?  I ask this because I tested my program with charset=utf-8 and question marks appeared in my text that was retrieved from my database.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: my apologies, missed this in my message box. do you still need assistance?

Comment: Josh,  Thank you for getting back to me on this.  I no longer need help with the code--I've discovered that my original code was correct. 
My true problem resides with the cookie itself that is being passed from my vendor.  I've created a new entry on StackOverflow: "Cookie value is truncated".  Please feel free to check out this submission and let me know if you have any input.  Thank you.  Sal